# Handling null value args in where conditions in apache ignite sql

Tags: sql, ignite

I can't figure out how to hit an index for following query:

```
select * from Cache 
where accountId = 'demo' 
and (? is null or country = ?) 
and (? is null or county = ?) 
and (? is null or province = ?) 
and (? is null or city = ?) 
and (? is null or locality = ?) 
order by createdAt desc
```

I have a orderedGroup index on cols (accountId, country, country, province, city, locality, createdAt(desc)). If I remove the isnull it is working. Maybe there is an alternative way to rewrite this in sql to be able to account for null args?

Comment: I am not familar with ignite and maybe this is wrong, but **isnull** or should be **IS NULL**? ISNULL in most DB is function.

Comment: yes you are right it's "IS NULL" can't edit my question for some reason tho

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite it using [`OR expansion`](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/optimizer-transformations:-or-expansion):

```
select * from Cache 
where accountId = 'demo' and ? is null
union all
select * from Cache 
where accountId = 'demo' and city = ?
```

Comment: yes I'm aware of this option, but the drawback if you have 10 conditions with each arg being optionally null, then it would require covering every possible permutation

Comment: @EvaldasMiliauskas Then there is no silver bullet. You won't get decent performance for 10 columns which every could be nullable. Please post your real case instead of simplified scenario. Your case is [kitchen sink procedure](http://sqlsentry.tv/the-kitchen-sink-procedure/) and I suggest to use `IF ELSE` or dynamically build final query.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I'll most likely go dynamic route as the query is generated in code anyway, I was just looking to avoid this extra complexity.